# Smooth matrix rotation

Tags: opengl, c++, glm, sdl2

I have a coded a simple example for a matrix rotation. The example rotates a sphere around its center. The problem is that the rotation is not running perfectly smooth and I'm wondering why.

Here is a minimal code sample:

```
float totalMs = 0.0f;
int animationDuration = 5000;

void update(float deltaMs) {
    totalMs += deltaMs;
    float degrees = (totalMs % animationDuration) / animationDuration * 360.0f;
    glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), radians(degrees), rotationAxis);

    //multiply modelViewMatrix by rotation matrix
    //and use the resulting matrix in shader to transform points
}
```

I'm programming in C++, using GLM Library for Maths, SDL2 for rendering context and OpenGL for the rendering.

Any hints what could cause the rendering to not look totally smooth?

Edit:
Ok I found out that the time needed for **SDL_GL_SwapWindow()** at the end of my gameLoop varies between <1ms and >30ms. What could be causing this?

Comment: What are usual values of `deltaMs` here? Are you sure it is not a framerate problem?

Comment: Looks like the `deltaMs` could be jittery/non-smooth.

Comment: You are right its because of the deltaMs, I made an edit to the question. Any Ideas?

Comment: You should reformulate and rename your question to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have v-sync enabled ( SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) ), SDL_GL_SwapWindow will wait until your monitor refreshes.